# Long and short barreled guns

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile

Projectiles containing delicate elecrtronic equipment may be damaged if they are subjected to high accelerations. For this reason, such projectiles may be fired from guns with long barrels but not from guns with short barrels.
       -Explain why a projectile fired from a long-barreled gun is subject to less acceleration than a projectile fired from a short-barrelled gun if the range is the same in both cases.
        This question has been a nightmare for me when i was in highschool and until now i cant have a good answer your help would be
 appreciated.

Comment: An idea would be to say that long-barreled guns = more friction thus less force and thus less acceleration and vice versa

Comment: A really good answer to this question was posted by Scott Manley on Youtube, but with a slightly different premise. Why can't we fire humans into space?

Comment: Take down your comment, it has nothing to do with friction. Its simply due to the equation E = Fdx. Given a longer barrel (dx), the required Force (F) is smaller for the same Muzzle Energy (E).

Comment: I would not think a projectile fired from a long-barreled gun is subject to less acceleration than a projectile fired from a short-barrelled gun.  Are you sure this is true?

Comment: If you say so then proove it. :/

Comment: @user1717828 The longer barrel doesn't subject it to less acceleration. The longer barrel subjects the bullet to longer acceleration. The physics involved is called "Internal Ballistics", but the important part is that a bullet accelerates because there is pressure behind it. There is pressure behind the bullet because there was an explosion AND the barrel prevents the gases from expanding. When the bullet leaves the barrel, it stops accelerating. The reason for the lower acceleration comes from the assumption of a constant muzzle velocity, ie the long barrel ALLOWS for lower acceleration.

Comment: @Aron, I'm with you right up until the last sentence.  I would think the work does on the bullet is $U=PV$, where the barrel volume $V$ has the same cross sectional area for both guns (but one is longer, obviously).  When the bullet has gone the full length of the short barrel and an equal length in the long barrel, why would the gas have done less work on the latter?

Comment: There is, a unstated assumption here that the two possibilities have *the same muzzle velocity*. That doesn't happen by accident, but careful design on the part of the experimenter. With that made explicit the approach here should be clearer.

Comment: @user1717828 The hot gas in the barrels do the same amount of work. The difference the barrel. Within the barrel, the hot gas can only do work on the bullet. Once the bullet leaves the barrel, the hot gas does work on both the bullet AND the atmosphere. The shorter barrel allows the gas to do MORE work on the atmosphere, thus, LESS work is done on the bullet.

Comment: @Aron, Right.  The shorter barrel does less work on the bullet.  So that bullet isn't going as fast.  Am I going crazy or can someone explain to me how this leads the two bullets to exit at the same speed?

Comment: @user1717828 Again, if you use the same charge it doesn't, but this problem is predicated on a hidden assumption: that the experimenter will rig each gun to get the single muzzle velocity that she desires. Whether the poor statement of the situation originates with Meadara or not I can't guess, but that is the only way this question makes sense.

Comment: @Aron We can fire humans into space. It's just a question of whether we want them to be alive to see the view from orbit :)

Comment: @user1717828 As dmckee said. The basic assumption is that the gun maker wants to make his guns all just as powerful. So to offset the smaller barrel, he uses a larger charge.

Comment: @dmckee Sorry for my previous post, but from the fact that they have the same range it seems pretty obvious that they have the same velocity when going out of the barrel and the same angle of elevation as well.  So the question is still unanswered

Comment: \@Meadara, I feel the opposite of you about the question.  If @dmckee is right and the guns and/or bullets are different beyond just the barrel length, then why is there any question at all?  The acceleration is different because they a) use different gun powder, b) fire different bullets, c) have a different quantity of gun powder, d) have different diameters and/or material inside the barrel, e) any combination of the above, f) other! We could speculate on and on, but if your question is about how manufacturers achieve this, the person to ask is a gunsmith, not a physicist.

Comment: @user1717828 you may be correct but you still did not provide an answer to the question above

Comment: -Last point of mine- If you can not provide an answer to the question  no need to give a -1 just because you are frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

Energy is force times distance. So if you want your projectile to have a kinetic energy of, for example, $E=1250 \text{ J}$, which, since $E=M\cdot v^2/2$, corresponds to a velocity of $v=500 \text{ m/s}$ if the weight of the bullet is $M=0.01 \text{ kg}$, you can either accelerate it with a force of $F=1250 \text{ N}$ for a distance of $x=1 \text{ m}$, or with a force of $F=125 \text{ N}$ for a distance of $x=10 \text{ m}$, or any other combination that gives you your required kinetic energy and therefore speed and range.

Answer (score 1):

The longer barrelled gun can contain the pressure of the explosive charge over a greater period of time than the short barrel, for the same initial charge, so the acceleration can be effectively reduced but produces an equal range for both guns.

Comment: Why would the bullet leave the two guns with the same velocity?  If I drop a marble down a short slide and a long slide, wouldn't it be going faster at the bottom of the long slide?

Comment: @user1717828 your thinking is correct, but the statement 'they have the same range' automatically induces the fact/assumption that they have the same initial velocity and obviously the same angle of elevation.  So one can easily assume that they are launched with the same initial energy E.

Comment: @user1717828  Sorry i cant modify my previous post but what i wanted to say is that your thinking is wrong,as they have the same potential energy at the beginning and it is gradually converted to K.E , so the corresponding velocity is only dependent on the height covered thus independent of the path taken. :/

Answer (score -1):

The short barrel gun has a high force because  $$F=GmM/r^2$$
for the long barrel has a long radius thus less force but short barrel gun has a small radius thus large force.

But $F=ma$ so $F$ varies directly as acceleration. The smaller the force the smaller the acceleration and the greater the force the greater the acceleration accounting for the high velocity.

Comment: Would you care so specify what are $G$, $M$ and $m$ in your answer?